Extending a line
As far as I understand, you can use the create_line() method to create a path with multiple points. For example, you can write the following:
points = [(10,20), (30, 40), (50,60)]
line = canvas.create_line(points)

The create_line() method flattens the parameters, so it’s equivalent to:
line = canvas.create_line(10,20, 30,40, 50,60)

(I’ve left spaces between the number pairs for clarity).
The line variable contains resource id of the line, but what, exactly is the line? Is it really a multi-segment object?
If so, it is possible to add another point to this object without re-creating it? Something like:
canvas.extend(line, (70,80))    #   I know this doesn’t work


There are multiple otions to do this, the most commonly used one is to call canvas.coords(id, *new_coords)

You have to keep coordinates on list, and later extend this list
and use canvas.coords(id, *new_coords) to update points in line.

EDIT:
You can also use cords(id) to get current points - and you don't have to keep original list.
line_points = canvas.coords(line_id)
print(line_points)    


Minimal working example:
There are two buttons which use canvas.coords():

to add new random point at the end of line
to move all points down

import tkinter as tk
import random

# --- functions ---

def add_point():
    line_points = canvas.coords(line_id)

    x = random.randint(10, 290)
    y = random.randint(10, 290)
    line_points.extend((x,y))

    canvas.coords(line_id, *line_points)
    
def move_down():
    line_points = canvas.coords(line_id)

    for i in range(1, len(line_points), 2):  # change only even items
        line_points[i] += 50

    canvas.coords(line_id, *line_points)
    
# --- main ---
    
root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg='white', width=300, heigh=300)
canvas.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='ADD POINT', command=add_point)
button.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='MOVE DOWN', command=move_down)
button.pack()

#---

line_points = [100, 100, 200, 100]
line_id = canvas.create_line(*line_points, fill='black')

#---

root.mainloop()

